# My CSS works on some computers but not others

Tags: html, css

**I have fixed the question and the code provided within the post**

I have been building a site on my PC laptop and I have tested it on IE Chrome and Firefox and it looked fine. I then emailed the site file to myself (compressed and as a google drive link) because I wanted to test it on a mac with Safari. For some reason when I opened up the html file in chrome on my mac, the website logo was stretched out vertically and Im not sure why because its the same browser I tested on with the original computer (chrome) and it still looks fine there. its the same problem when I tried testing it on safari.

Is there something in my code that could cause this issue?

The image Im specifically referring to is cover.png located in the div with the class of "cover".

The desired result is that the image is shown with its normal proportion and not stretched vertically.

specifically I need to know what I did that makes it look different on two computers when the same browser is being used.

Here's my code for the applicable portion of the site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Complete Bootstrap 4 Website Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>


<body>
<!-- Navigation -->
<!--
8 - Navbar with links center, toggler right
    The links collapse into the mobile menu
-->
<section>
<nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top bg-primary flex-row">
    <a href class="navbar-brand d-flex w-50 mr-0"><img src="img/logo8.png"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCenter">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100" id="navbarCenter">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-sm-auto">
            <li id ="nav-item" style="padding-left:2em">
                <a class="nav-link" style="color:white;" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>

                        <li id ="nav-item" style="padding-left:2em">
                <a class="nav-link" style="color:white;" href="#">Resume</a>
            </li>

                        <li id ="nav-item" style="padding-left:2em">
                <a class="nav-link" style="color:white;" href="#">Projects</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex w-50"><!-- placeholder to keep links centered--></div>
        </nav>

<div class="text-center"></div>


<div id="paralax0">
<div class="cover" style="padding-top:25vh;">
    <img style="width:600px;" src="./img/cover.png">
</div>
<div class="coverlinks">
    <div class "icon" style="padding: 0px 20px 70px 20px;"><a class="link" href="#"><img src="./img/resume.png"></a></div>
    <div class "icon" style="padding: 0px 20px 70px 20px;"><a class="link" href="#"><img src="./img/mywork.png"></a></div>
</div>
</div>

</section>



CSS:

section{
background:url('../img/shoecase blank4.png');
min-height: 100%;
}

section{
  position:relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#paralax0{
  min-height: 100%;
}

.cover{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.coverlinks{
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why but if you add `align-items:center` to the `.cover` class it will fix it.